# How can I design this layout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a parent linear layout.

I need to put three buttons at the bottom of screen horizontally aligned not from XML but through Java code.
Button 1 should be at left of screen
Button 2 should be at bottom of screen
Button 3 should be at right of screen

This is the layout need to be designed:

[image]

What I understand is I have to add a relative layout to my parent layout.
And some rules for the button.

This is what I tried

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainl);
    rl=new RelativeLayout(this);
    b1=new Button(this);
    b2=new Button(this);
    b3=new Button(this);
    b1.setText("Button 1");
    b2.setText("Button 2");
    b3.setText("Button 3");
    rl.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    rl.addView(b1);
    rl.addView(b2);
    rl.addView(b3);

    l.addView(rl);

}
```

And also the buttons are not coming at bottom. They are coming at top of screen.

Activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding button to RelativeLayout run time, you have to pass params values.

Try for placing button `b1` on left:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
rl.addView(b1, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    rl.addView(b1, params);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    rl.addView(b3, params1);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            ( (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    rl.addView(b2, params2);



LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txt1.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(LinearLayout.BOTTOM, 1);

rl.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: It works great for me. But the buttons are not at the bottom of screen. They are coming at the top of the screen. How do I keep them at bottom.

Comment: what is txt1 over here? and also no BOTTOM for linear layout recognized

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    rl.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    rl.addView(b1, params1);
    rl.addView(b2, params3);
    rl.addView(b3, params2);

    l.addView(rl);
```

Comment: Buttons not coming at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I think you are using linear layout height as wrap_content in activity_main.xml file. right?

Comment: If yes then change layout_height to fill_parent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45872/discussion-between-shink-and-sonali8890)

Comment: thn post your activity_main.xml file

Comment: Added activity_main.xml file

Comment: I dont want parent layout to be horizontal

Comment: see if you use linear layout as parent and set orientation to vertical then above code won't work. Either you have to use relative layout in place of linear layout or you can set  android:gravity="bottom" to linear layout, but in this case all your child layout will be placed from bottom instead of top

Answer (score 0):

I have created layout programmatically use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout layout; 
    private RelativeLayout lay;
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ff);
        lay = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lay.setLayoutParams(layout_params);

        //lay.setLayoutParams(layout_params);
        btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("ButtonA");
        btn2 = new Button(this);
        btn2.setText("ButtonB");
        btn3 = new Button(this);
        btn3.setText("ButtonC");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams button_params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        button_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(button_params1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams button_params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button_params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        button_params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        btn2.setLayoutParams(button_params2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams button_params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button_params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        button_params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        btn3.setLayoutParams(button_params3);

        lay.addView(btn1);
        lay.addView(btn2);
        lay.addView(btn3);
        layout.addView(lay);



    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot have a parent relative layout. Parent layout should be linear only. And i need to add relative layout to parent linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And in JAVA file :

```
 LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(getBaseContext());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        Button btn1 = new Button(getBaseContext());
        Button btn2 = new Button(getBaseContext());
        Button btn3 = new Button(getBaseContext());

        btn1.setText("One");
        btn2.setText("Two");
        btn3.setText("Three");

        ll.addView(btn1, params1);
        ll.addView(btn2, params2);
        ll.addView(btn3, params3);

        main.addView(ll, params);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I want relative layout to be created by java code not through xml

Comment: So your parent LINEAR LAYOUT is in XML file .Right??

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please check updates.It works for me.

Comment: It solves half of my problem. It works great. But I also need to put these buttons at the bottom of the screen. Do you know how to do that?